# Incorrect usage of that in relative clauses

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

I was in a class of relative clauses and, out of context and in order to give an example, I said:

> I know a man that he lives in London.

However my teacher said that using the 'that he' pronouns is wrong and they should be replaced by 'who'. Is that correct? Why? I found later that the 'that' pronoun could be used either with people or objects so now I can't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Your teacher is correct. _He_ should be omitted, and _who_ is better than _that_ because the man is a person, not a thing.

Comment: Note that in English, the inverted question mark ¿ is not used.

Comment: oops now you know what is my native language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your teacher is right that "that he" is incorrect. It's incorrect because "that" is the subject of the relative clause, but so is "he", and there cannot be two subjects, so "he" is wrong.

These are the two correct options:

> I know a man **that** lives in London.
> I know a man **who** lives in London.

"Who" is usually preferred for people, but it's not a grammar rule.